# R: Calculating percentage for Likert scale and creating barplots with those percentages

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, bar-chart

I have data from Male(1) and Female(2) with responses on Likert Scale. I am trying to calculate the percentage for each one of them (ex. Male with response 1 out of all 226 respondents). Thus, the percentage would need to represent % out of all 226, so that I can see the percentage of each respondent.

The barplots are quite pretty, but I cannot turn the y scale into percentage (it is currently set on values).

This is my input:

```
barplot(table(Short$Gen,Short$optq18), beside=T, cex.names=0.7, 
        legend.text=c("Male", "Female"), args.legend=list(x=3.5,y=60,cex=0.8),
        col=c("bisque1", "cyan4"),
        xlab = "It is important to control monthly expenses",
        ylab = "Percentage",
        )
text(1.4,5, "0,44%", cex=0.6)
text(2.4,4, "0%", cex=0.6)
text(4.6,8.5, "2,21%", cex=0.6)
text(5.6,7, "1,76%", cex=0.6)
text(7.5,18, "6,63%", cex=0.6)
text(8.5,26.5, "10,17%", cex=0.6)
text(10.6,37, "15%", cex=0.6)
text(11.6,47.5, "19,4%", cex=0.6)
text(13.5,41, "16,8%", cex=0.6)
text(14.6,63, "17,43%", cex=0.6)
```

And the barplots:

[image]

And a sample from the data:

[image]

where Country has 3 levels, Gender has 2, optq has 5 (1,2,3,4,5) Likert scale

Comment: It will be easier if you provide a sample of data so we can investigate.

Comment: I have now uploaded it

Comment: I can't use your dataset as I'll have to type everything, but I'll post an example of some code you can use

Comment: This is just a dplyr mutate question in disguise, and hence a duplicate and probably should be closed. We don't strictly need any of the ggplot stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# example data
dt = data.frame(Gen = c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2),
                optq18 = c(1,2,2,2,3,2,1,1,1,3))

library(tidyverse)

dt %>%
  group_by(optq18) %>%                                            # for each question number
  count(Gen) %>%                                                  # count gender type
  mutate(Prc = round(n/sum(n),2),                                 # get percentage of gender up to 2 decimal points
         Gen = ifelse(Gen == 1, "Male", "Female")) %>%            # update variable
  ungroup() %>%                                                   # forget the grouping
  mutate(Prc_text = paste0(Prc*100, "%")) %>%                     # update how percentages appear
  ggplot(aes(factor(optq18), Prc, fill=Gen))+                     # plot
  geom_bar(position = "dodge", stat = "identity")+                # add bars
  geom_text(aes(label=Prc_text), position = position_dodge(width=1), size=8)+  # add percentages on top of bars
  xlab("")+                                                       # no x axis title
  ylab("Percentage")+                                             # y axis title
  labs(caption = "It is important to control monthly expenses")+  # add your comment
  theme(plot.caption = element_text(hjust = 0.5))+                # put comment in the middle
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("Female"="green", "Male"="orange"))  # pick your colours
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! This helped me a lot :) I wanted to see the responses /226, so now I have all the percentages I want. But they have too many decimals. Do you have any idea how can I remain to two? As 0,4424525 -> 0,44. And one more thing - how can I change the colors? I have more barplots and different colors would be useful :) thank you!

Comment: Thanks a lot! Looks way better than my initial barplot :D